# When To Use Certain Operators In Unity Scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine, operators

I posted this same script a few hours ago and its for parallaxing in a 2D platformer. I'm fairly confident that I understand most of it. The only thing that has really been bothering me is the multiplication and addition operators. Now I understand that the operators themselves are pretty easy to understand but the way they are used sometimes confuses me. So this script isn't actually the first time I've had trouble with these operators.

```
float parallax = (previousCamPos.x - cam.position.x) * parallaxScales[i];

float backgroundTargetPosX = backgrounds[i].position.x + parallax;
```

These two lines of code in particular are what I am talking about in this case. At the most, All I've really been able to do is make educated cases about how they work. It seems like in the second line that the two values are just being paired up with each other and stored in a variable, so that when the camera moves the backgrounds will move with it. The first line seems a little harder to interpret though, and I can't really make sense of it or really describe how these values are interacting with each other. Could someone help shed some light on why each operator is used and when it is appropriate to use one over the other?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Parallaxing : MonoBehaviour {


public Transform [] backgrounds;    
private float [] parallaxScales;   
public float smoothing = 1f;      

private Transform cam;             
private Vector3 previousCamPos;    


void Awake () 

{
cam = Camera.main.transform; 
}

void Start ()

{
previousCamPos = cam.position;
parallaxScales = new float[backgrounds.Length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++)  
{
    parallaxScales[i] = backgrounds[i].position.z * -1;

}
}

void Update () 
{

for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++)

{

    float parallax = (previousCamPos.x - cam.position.x) * parallaxScales[i];

    float backgroundTargetPosX = backgrounds[i].position.x + parallax;   


    Vector3 backgroundTargetPos = new Vector3 (backgroundTargetPosX, backgrounds[i].position.y, backgrounds[i].position.z);


    backgrounds[i].position = Vector3.Lerp (backgrounds[i].position, backgroundTargetPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);

}

previousCamPos = cam.position; 
}
}
```

Comment: By the way, Unity script is Unity's version of Javascript. You are using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely worth your time to study and learn [linear algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra).

The first line has two calculations (and an assignment operation), let's dissect it.

```
(previousCamPos.x - cam.position.x)
```

This is finding the change in movement between frames (the delta). So if the camera's X was 22 last frame, and it's 25 this frame, the value returned will be -3.

Since this is a parallax, we don't want a 1 to 1 movement, so we [scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication) the delta to dampen/exaggerate the movement. The paralaxScales is the Z position of the background inverted (negative.) So if the background has a z of 10, the scalar is -10, so the assignment will end up looking something like this (using our made up numbers).

```
float parallax = -3 * -10; // which is, of course, 30
```

So now we have exaggerated the movement ten fold! Now we apply that delta to the background position:

```
float backgroundTargetPosX = backgrounds[i].position.x + parallax; // parallax is 30
```

If the scalar value had been one, then the parallax would have been the exact movement of the camera, and we would have a 1 to 1 movement, so the background position would move at the same rate as the camera.

I hope this helps, and do take the time to study up on [linear algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra)!

Comment: Alright Thank you very much! This was a very good explanation. I'll be sure to study up on linear algebra now in order to better understand the code I am writing.